# ThreadingModel Free crashes the WCF service

Tags: wcf, com, mta

I have a non-singleton WCF (standalone) service running some COM objects. In non-WCF environments, using Thread.Start, these COM objects happily run in parallel in different threads, utilising all CPUs and completing around the same time.

However, when I try using them in a specific WCF service, things get strange.

When in the registry *ApartmentState* is set to *Both*, WCF works, but the tasks seem to be serial, waiting for each other's completion. The CPU usage never exceeds a share of 1 CPU. It's as it is forced to run in STA.

When in the registry *ApartmentState* is set to *Free*, it crashes.

I simply don't get it. Is this some kind of piece of plumbing getting in the way?

My WCF service class has the following attributes:

[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]

The COM objects are static / global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I might have an answer. Posting in case someone else comes across a similar mystery. The older version was STA only, and the Interop was set to be embedded. Additionally, a prototype of a method was changed. Seemingly, parts taken from the embedded Interop clashed with the COM itself.

Once I changed the setting to No and recompiled everything, it become normal.